# R Shiny: Combining with Rvest

Tags: r, shiny, rvest

I am trying to use R Shiny with the `rvest` package so when a date is selected as an input I can lookup a webpage based on it and scrape some of the data.  When I input the full address it works but when I try and combine the reactive `input$date` I get an error message that I "cannot coerce type closure to vector or type character". I have been searching around and have been unable to find a solution.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  column(4,wellPanel(
    dateInput('date',
              label = 'Date Input: yyyy-mm-dd',
              value = Sys.Date())
    )
  ),
  column(6,
     verbatimTextOutput("Name")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$Name <- renderText({
    paste(as.character(Name))
  })
  ds <- reactive({input$date})
  address <- paste0("http://www.baseballpress.com/lineups/",ds)
  BBPress <- html(address)
  Name <- BBPress %>%
    html_node(".player-link") %>%
    html_text()
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```